# Want to cancel the browser's back button with next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to cancel the browser's back button with next.js.

```
  // not blocked...
  Router.onRouteChangeStart = (url) => {
    return false;
  };
```

Is there a function to stop browser back in next.js?

Comment: You can't prevent the user from going back or forward. The best you could do is use onbeforeunload to tell the user some message to see if they want to stay or leave. But you cannot on your own prevent navigation away from the page, that would lead to some very annoying pages (just think of a full ad page that you couldn't navigate away from).

Comment: Have you ever been to Microsoft documentation where you wanted to go back and it wouldn't let you? Imagine how that would make you feel. Browser makers managed to overcome that by making the back button so that it can go back further than just the previous page, so your idea which is likely to annoy users would be easily thwarted anyway. (And even so, I still have unkind thoughts towards whoever thought it would be a good idea to try to stop me doing what I wanted to do.) Perhaps you could find a more elegant way for a user to go back if that is what they need to do.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling the back button is a clear UX no-no. But there are rare cases where disabling the back button is an absolute necessity. Think of a web-based exam application where test-takers cannot navigate back to the previous section once they’ve moved on.

Applying the instructions given in this [medium](https://subwaymatch.medium.com/disabling-back-button-in-react-with-react-router-v5-34bb316c99d7) article, I have been able to force my app to stay on the route, even when clicking the back button in the browser. However I am a beginner and if there are some better solutions, please edit.

```
useEffect(() => { 
  if (router.asPath === '/?step=2') {
    window.onpopstate = () => { 
      history.go(1);
    };
  }
}, [router]);
```

Comment: Nice idea, it works. But does not preserve the page state like input fields.

Comment: the one I was looking for exactly. How to implement this behavior in mobile devices too, which the going back scenario is by swipe back by fingers. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Check this

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        history.pushState(null, '', router.asPath);
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
            history.pushState(null, '', router.asPath);
        });
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(router.asPath === '/?step=2'){
  window.onpopstate = () => {
   router.replace(router.pathname)
   history.go(1)
  }
 }
})
```

Comment: Already given answer, what is change in your answer.

Comment: Please explain why you added `router.replace(router.pathname)` to an existing answer.