How to get rid of Chrome default page once user logged in
I am using Next.js router.replace once the user enters the home page. It's working great, but the issue is that the back button is still enabled. If I click the back button, it goes to Chrome's default page. How can I get rid of this?
router.replace({
 pathname: '/home',
});


Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001761/want-to-cancel-the-browsers-back-button-with-next-js

@MCNaveen, thanks. but It doesn't helped me

router.replace doesn't add a new entry in the browser's history stack, it just replaces the current entry. Could you try router.push ?

@RagulCS, its for login btn onclick. if i used that, login page will be on stack. so i used replace

What you can do is use router.push as Ragul CS suggested - but I'd add checks and redirects.
If the user is on the login page, we can automatically redirect them to the home page if they're logged in and vice versa, something like this in src/middleware.ts:
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest, _: NextResponse) {
  if(request.nextUrl.pathname === 'login') {
    // if user is signed in - redirect to /home
  } 

  if(request.nextUrl.pathname === 'home') {
    //if user is not signed in - redirect to /login
  }
}

This way you don't have to change the way the back button works.
